# FIREBASE: How do you find your google project number in google firebase?

Tags: firebase

I can't find the google project  number in "General" or "Cloud Messaging". Not much else to say. Ideas?

Comment: [Instructions here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158840?hl=en).  Project Number appears to be the same as Sender ID shown in the Firebase settings for Cloud Messaging.

Answer (score 15):

Go to the Google Developer Console : https://console.developers.google.com

Select Your Project.

Go to Settings and Utilities (3 point dropdown icon left of your profile pic on top right).

Go to Project Settings.

You will get your project number there.

Answer (score 1):

**In Google Developer Console:**

```
Select the project > Settings & Utilities (Near user icon on top right) > Project Settings
```

You will find project number there.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you can get it using gcloud CLI using below command:

```
gcloud projects list --format="table(projectNumber,projectId)" --filter="my-firebase-project"
```

Replace `my-firebase-project` with your desired project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://console.cloud.google.com
Select the project you want
Click on Dashboard
It'll show up there

Answer (score 0):

This worked to set my PROJECT_NUMBER variable for me:

```sh
PROJECT_NUMBER=$(gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT_ID} --format 'value(projectNumber)')
```

`PROJECT_ID` is your text string PROJECT_ID you use elsewhere in Google commands. You should be able to see this easily in the console UI.

For those unfamiliar, the `$( . . . )` above is a [subshell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process) which calls the `gcloud` sdk to populate the `PROJECT_NUM` variable.