# Google Search Console API suggests enabling API for unfamiliar project number

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-search-console

I have an account that is the verified owner for a property listed in the Google Search Console. I'm working to set up API access to it. I have a principal created that has access to each of the Google Cloud projects that I intend to query the data from. I've enabled the Google Search Console API for each of these projects.

After I authenticate the principal via OAuth2 and use the access token (including the 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly' scope) to make a POST request to the [query endpoint](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/searchanalytics/query), I get an error message back that reads in part:

> Google Search Console API has not been used in project 256595xxxxxx before or it is disabled

I searched this number in my Google Cloud Console and manually clicked through each of my properties and it doesn't match any of the projects on my account. How do I identify which project this number is referring to and/or how do I change it to point to one of my own Google Cloud properties so I might access its API?

Note: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68722059) speaks to what it is I'm trying to do (but with Google Search Console API), except that the error doesn't reflect my project ID, so I'm stumped about how to move forward with enabling the API on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This didn't take long to solve. After listing all the projects in the Google Cloud CLI per the first half of the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55263157), I was able to identify the project as that which is used as the service principal to do the authentication in the first place (and not actually an account I intend to export any of the data to).